# Is there is Any possibility for Math.Ceiling Operator with two arguments?

Tags: c#, math, operator-keyword, ceil

I want an output of `14.45` and I have `p = 14.445`, if I use `Output=Math.Round(p,2);` I get the output of `14.44`,

I couldn't able to use `Math.Ceiling` here because it consists of two arguments.

Is there is any way of getting output of `14.45`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Math.Round with 3 parameters, that let's you pick how 5 is rounded, and you can get behaviour you want. Otherwise you can also do `(Math.Floor(p * 100) + 1) / 100`, but I suggest the Round :)

EDIT:
Code sample : `Math.Round(p, precision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`

But `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` is just a guess since, some other values of the `MidpointRounding` will also produce `14.45` from `14.445`.

Comment: Please show the code to get what the OP has asked for. Showing `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` is crucial for how this answer works.

Comment: @Enigmativity I did not show any particular MidpointRounding, because from one example it is not really possible to be sure which of them OP wanted